# Original version of Radak on borders of Eretz Yisrael after Moshiach comes

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, eretz-yisrael, manuscripts

Sefaria offers a translation of the [Radak's commentary to Bereishis 26:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Radak_on_Genesis.26.23.1?vhe=Presburg_:_A._Schmid,_1842&lang=bi). The translation of that Radak says:

> ויעל משם באר שבע. This was not far away from Gerar as we already
> explained. As to the reason for the expression ויעל, “he went up,” the
> reason for this is that the part of the Land of Israel which is known
> as the traditional Land of Israel was on a spiritually higher level
> than the part occupied by the Philistines. This is also why we find
> the expression ויעלו פלשתים in Judges 15,9 (against Shimshon) as well
> as the phrase uttered by King Sha-ul in Samuel I 14,36 נרדה אחרי
> פלשתים, “Let us pursue the Philistines by descending.” This expression
> occurs again and again. [this seems unnecessary as any student of the
> topography of Eretz Yisrael knows that the Philistines lived in the
> coastal strip, i.e. the topographically lowest region of the country,
> so that considerations distinguishing between areas of higher sanctity
> and lesser sanctity are hardly needed to help us understand the
> wording of the Torah here. Ed.] All these stories about the digging of
> the wells and the names they were called by were intended to inform us
> that in the part of Eretz Yisrael traditionally promised to Avraham,
> his son Yitzchok was digging according to his undisputed right. In
> those areas he also did not encounter opposition when naming these
> wells. All of this was an indication to them of which parts of Eretz
> Yisrael G’d had meant for them to plant seed in, i.e. the part of the
> land that G’d would give to the Israelites in the first instance.
> (under Joshua).The regions in which the Philistines dwelled did not
> really come under full control of the Israelites until many hundreds
> of years later. This accounts for the ongoing wars at intervals
> between the Israelites and the Philistines. These skirmishes were
> basically border-wars, neither side planning to conquer the territory
> of the other permanently. [according to the author the problem would
> be permanently settled only in Messianic times. Ed.] It is an
> outstanding issue similar to the territory of three Canaanite tribes,
> the Kenite, Knizite and Kadmoni, which formed part of G’d’s promise to
> Avraham in chapter 15 at the covenant between the pieces but has never
> yet been under Jewish sovereignty.

The translation/interpretation seems to be from Eliyahu Munk, HaChut Hameshulash. I was wondering, this piece on Sefaria has an addition that says:

> This accounts for the ongoing wars at intervals between the Israelites and the Philistines. These skirmishes were basically border-wars, neither side planning to conquer the territory of the other permanently. **[according to the author the problem would be permanently settled only in Messianic times. Ed.]**

Does anyone know if this latter, namely that the ongoing wars between the Israelites and the Philistines, which are basically border-wars, will be fought until Moshiach comes, after which the borders of Eretz Yisrael will also include Gaza? Are there maybe manuscripts, original translations etc.. that say this, or is this just an addition from Eliyahu Munk?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. That note is pshat what the Radak says in Hebrew. "אבל פלשתים אע"פ שהיא מארץ ישראל לא הוחזקה בידם לפיכך רבו עמהם על הגבול, וכל זה להודיעם שלא תהיה מוחזקת בידם כלה אע"פ שחלקוה לא הוחזקה בידם עד באחרונה לימות המשיח". See also [here](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Parshan/Radak/Bereshit/26.23#m5e0n6).

Comment: @Harel13 my question was whether these latter words regarding Moshiach were also included in the original manuscript of that Radak, or that it is something the translator added in. I don't know where to find the original words of that Radak.

Comment: Alhatorah also includes that so I'd guess that it is in the original. They also included a note regarding manuscripts so it seems legit.

Comment: "wars between the Israelites and the Philistines, which are basically border-wars, will be fought until Moshiach comes"  The Philistines don't exist anymore, so how could we fight them in the messianic era?